# C# SQL parameter query with in

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)

i have the follwing code:

```
var myCommand = new SqlCommand();
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
myCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value = username;
return _dbConnection.ExecuteQuery("Select * from customer where username = @username");
```

now i need to adapt the query for more values. I want to do something like this:

```
var myCommand = new SqlCommand();
foreach (string username in usernames){
  myCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
  myCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value = username;
}
return _dbConnection.ExecuteQuery("Select * from customer where username in @username");
```

Is that possible? How?

Thank you!

BR Stefan

Answer (score 2):

Each parameter needs to be unique:

```
var paramNames = new List<string>();
var myCommand = new SqlCommand();
foreach (string username in usernames){
  var paramName = "@user" + paramNames.Count;
  myCommand.Parameters.Add(paramName, SqlDbType.NVarChar);
  myCommand.Parameters[paramName].Value = username;
  paramNames.Add(paramName);
}
return _dbConnection.ExecuteQuery("Select * from customer where username in (" + string.Join(",", paramNames) + ")");
```

You will get sql like this:

```
SELECT * from customer where username in (@user0, @user1, @user2)
```

It doesn't help much from a query plan caching standpoint, but you will get the benefits of not being vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

I like to do stuff like this in two methods.

```
public void ReadDatabase(string[] values)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        using (var rd = GetData(value))
        {
            if (!rd.Read())
                throw new OMGException("FAILED!");

            Console.WriteLine(rd["UserId"].ToString());
        }
    }
}

public IDataReader GetData(string value)
{
    using(var cm = _connectionWhatever.CreateCommand())
    {
        cm.CommandText = @"
            Select UserId
            From MyTable
            Where UserName = @User
        ";
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("User", value);
        return cm.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

This is just to give you some ideas. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Virtual +1 for `OMGException`!

Answer (score 2):

Change the code to this

```
    var myCommand = new SqlCommand();
    int i = 0;
    string param = string.Empty;

    foreach (string username in usernames)
    {
        string paramName = string.Format("@username{0}", i);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(paramName, SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        myCommand.Parameters[paramName].Value = username;
        param += string.Format("  (username={0}) or", paramName);

        i++;
    }
    param = param.Substring(0, param.Length - 2);
    return _dbConnection.ExecuteQuery("Select * from customer where " + param);
```

Comment: also using or instead of IN is more faster

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by passing an XML data type to the Query and searching within that.

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '<IDs><ID>1</ID><ID>2</ID></IDs>'

SELECT ID.value('.', 'int') AS ID
FROM @x.nodes('/IDs/ID') as IDS(ID)
```

So in this instance you could do:

```
var myCommand = new SqlCommand();
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@usernames", SqlDbType.Xml);
string usernames = "<Usernames>"
foreach (string username in usernames){
   usernames+= String.Format("<username>{0}</username>", username);
}
usernames += "</Usernames>"
myCommand.Parameters["@usernames"].Value = usernames;
return _dbConnection.ExecuteQuery("Select * from customer where username in (SELECT
    username.value('.', 'nvarchar') AS Username
    FROM @x.nodes('/Usernames/Username') as Usernames(Username))");
```

However, syntax may need checking

Comment: Not exactly the most performant option, but the concept should work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it exactly the way you are thinking with the loop because you would be adding the same parameter multiple times with different values, however this may be helpful:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555266  (its in VB but you can probably find a c# example or translate)

The way I would solve this myself is to make this into a stored procedure as its just good practice (benefits such as added security, efficiency, code reuse etc), then have your procedure accept a parameter of XML.   In your C# application convert the Usernames collection to XML then pass that into the SP.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you really want to you could do this entirely through string manipulation.

```
string sql = "Select * from customer where username in (";

string comma = "";
foreach(string s in usernames)
{
   sql += comma + "'" + CleanSqlParameter(s) + "'";
   comma = ", ";
}

return _dbConnection.ExecuteQuery(sql);
```

This would be messy!  But if you feel like you need to construct the query entirely in C#, here's a way to do it. I've had success with this method.

Comment: It's important to ensure that the `usernames` object is not built from textboxes on a page for example, or else this will be prone to SQL Injection

Comment: @Curt -Absolutely correct.  I actually have a procedure in the cleanup section that makes sure no unsafe words are in the query such as 'N, DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT'.  This was just a sample.

Comment: Yeah I think this is an acceptable solution as long as users don't have a way of manipulating the values in the usernames object

Comment: @Curt - It's worse than that. Everything in the database was entered into a computer by a human at some point. They may have been safe when first put in, but on cycling them through in this way you now have what is called a 2nd Order Sql Injection vulnerability. This is just a **really BAD way to build your query**, no matter where the data comes from.

Comment: @MAW74656 - A cleanup procedure is a weak and failure-prone substitute for good parameterization. There are better ways.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Thats a good point Joel, I suppose even if this is a back-end script somewhere, those usernames would have been put into the database another way, say paramertised queries, so SQL Injection would've been avoided, but the data would still be stored, and therefore still a danger if used in this script.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn -I don't disagree with the possible danger, but I do think it depends on the use case.  If this is a database admin trying to create a remote way (in asp.Net webpage) of viewing a list of users, then I think its ok.  For general consumption though, I agree its dangerous.  I would greatly prefer using some kind of Like in the where clause or some other method.